# What biological systems are affected by Vitamin B6 (or B vitamins in general)?

Tags: human-biology, metabolism, circadian-rhythms, vitamins

B vitamins and particularly the B6 vitamin appears to the one of the main ingredients in energy drinks.

There has been anecdotal evidence from people interested in dreaming that ingestion of vitamin B6 at night time changes the pattern of dreaming and is likely to produce "lucid" dreams.

**From a biological standpoint, what is the effect of the B6 vitamin on the human body and brain?** Do other animals require the same vitamin?

Are B vitamins in any way related to the circadian rhythm regulation within some organ systems? Does it speed up metabolism?

I would be grateful for any scholarly papers on the subject or keywords that I may look up myself.

Thank you!

Comment: More related to [this question](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/2320/how-does-laughing-gas-n2o-work) but long term exposure/abuse of laughing gas is linked to severe B6 deficiency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main effect, of vitamin B6, is neurological, becouse  moderate variations in the intracellular concentration of pyridoxal 5'-phosphate (PLP), the biologically active form of vitamin B6, can have pronounced modulatory effects on steroid-induced gene expression. So you cannot get the effect of stress hormones.

Also neurological damage has been reported on doses from excess of 500 mg/d. Check this papers http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2661220 and http://www.fasebj.org/content/8/3/343.short